# Как узнать свой логин

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt4

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как узнать имя пользователя, который сейчас залогинен в linux? Т.е. свой логин. Нужен аналог whoami, для использования в коде программы.

Comment: `man getlogin`, `getenv("USERNAME")`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
#include <unistd.h>

int getlogin_r(char *buf, size_t bufsize);
```

или классический способ:

```
/* whoami.c */
#define _PROGRAM_NAME "whoami"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pwd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  register struct passwd *pw;
  register uid_t uid;
  int c;

  uid = geteuid ();
  pw = getpwuid (uid);
  if (pw)
    {
      puts (pw->pw_name);
      exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
  fprintf (stderr,"%s: cannot find username for UID %u\n",
       _PROGRAM_NAME, (unsigned) uid);
  exit (EXIT_FAILURE);

}
```

<sub>[enSO - How to get the username in C/C++ in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953424/how-to-get-the-username-in-c-c-in-linux)</sub>